# Mediaquery: in one CSS, or separated per condition?

Tags: css, html, media-queries

maybe its not a real question...
Im talking about media queries. Lets imagine a CSS consist 100 lines, and when the screen is smaller than 200 pixel, another CSS triggers - but it only has a few lines, for example float something left.
Once I heard its not good to use many CSS / JS files. So, which method should I use: if I have mobile/tablet/desktop design, should I separate them to 3 CSS file, or put them into one? But the media query can only accept external files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 100 lines in a CSS file any optimization is not worth your time. Keep it in one file.

You can learn how to use media queries here:
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: oh I didnt knew I can keep it in one file that way